# MYSQL insert syntax

Tags: mysql, database, insert, tags

I have some problems with inconsistent data that I want to load into a mysql database. Is it possible to write an INSERT statement that searches for unordered tags?

As an example I have a file with lines like these:

```
POET="Adams, A."  GENDER=F DATE=1996 DATE2=1996 NAME="BLURB" 

POET="Adcock, F. and Tartler, G."  NAME="THE COANDA EFFECT" GENDER=F DATE=1989 DATE2=1989
```

The whole file is unordered in terms of its tags. Is it possible to look for tags on an unordered line in an insert statement or do I have to parse the whole file first?  In the Table the columns would be: Poet, Name, Gender, Date, Date2. I want the insert statement to read the lines and put the appropriate information in the table. Also, the quotations are not around all of the information but the tags are always in caps followed by an equals sign.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't really expect MYSQL being able to *parse* any custom format out in the wild. For this one, you will probably have to write few lines of code yourself. My guess is using shell script it shouldn't be so complicated...

Comment: Thanks Sylvain, thats what I thought. I just wanted to be sure as I am new to mysql. I will just parse the file and reorder each line. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the details are mixed up and not all records have all fields, I would have one table with a row for each record. Assuming that the poet name is always there I would put that field into that table, along with an auto increment key.

Then move the rest of the fields into a separate table, with multiple rows per poet, one for each tag. Keyed by the tag name and the key of the poet from the other table.